# Custom posts stopped working after moving to new domain

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm working on an existing wordpress site (with a custom made theme). We had kept the website in a subdomain, it uses CPT UI and Custom Fields plugins for a bunch of custom post types the site requires. But, when we moved it to root domain accessing any custom post leads to 404 error.

I've checked settings for CPT UI and custom fields plugin everything seems to be fine. The database is also same as before, I can't figure out this error please help!

Comment: Not an expert in this field, but when I have this kind of problems, I refresh htaccess file, sometimes it helps. On permalink settings screen I select "plain" a click save to refresh it. If it helps, then return to normal permalink structure and save.

Answer (score 0):

I had to flush my permalinks, so I went to Settings > Permalinks and just clicked save changes.